# python linux create gui without window manager and desktop

Tags: python

Hello i want to create a gui app that works without a window manager or X server.
like the old graphic applications that were launched in msdos

like this:

[image]

i want a gui with buttons, color and print images/icons.

I'm not sure which lib could do this, I was thinking of pysdl2, do you think this is the right option?

Comment: In what environment are you expecting to run this code? Any modern system has a window manager, and I don't think you can get around it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write directly to framebuffer yourself instead of letting your X Server and your Window Manager to do the heavy lifting for you. For this there is this Python library: https://pythonhosted.org/fbpy/